# JPA - "Unable to build entity manager factory"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I want to add a data into my database. I am using Oracle DB, Jboss eap 6.1 in my project.

When I run my test class, I get this exception. How can I solve this problem? Please help me. I am sorry for my bad english.

Test.java

```
package com.toyota.route;

import com.toyota.route.SysadmUserEntity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        EntityManager em;

        SysadmUserEntity user = new SysadmUserEntity();
        user.setFirstName("onur");
        user.setLastName("ozcan");
        user.setPassword("12355");
        user.setSysadmUid("1");
        user.setUsername("aonurozcan");

        //-----------------------------------

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Toyota-Deneme");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

        et.begin();

        em.persist(user);

        et.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="Toyota-Deneme" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.toyota.route.SysadmUserEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myUsername" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="myPassword" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>toyota</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.toyota</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

EDIT
Stacktrace

```
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:58 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Toyota-Deneme
    ...]
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:58 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.9.Final}
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE]
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=TOYOTAROUTE, password=****}
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Desteklenmeyen özellik
Nis 20, 2015 8:34:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.toyota.route.Test.main(Test.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: place the whole stacktrace, it actually says why it cannot create one.

Comment: I added the stacktrace. Thank you.

Comment: NullPointerException not very informative, there were not other errors or causeby below? The only thing I can think of is that it should be <persistence-unit name="Toyota-Deneme" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> as you manage the transaction yourself and you did not configure transaction provider.

Answer (score 0):

You are using manually managed persistence context and transactions so you need the

```
<persistence-unit name="Toyota-Deneme" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

instead of `transaction-type="JTA"`

I tested myself that the wrong transaction type raises that obscured NullPointerException

Comment: I changed transaction-type JTA to RESOURCE_LOCAL but i still get same exception. Thank you.

Comment: make sure you cleaned the project, sometimes IDE cache the persistence, it happen to me a lot. Good test for the caching is changing password to wrong one to get connection error. The transaction should defenitelly be local so at least that is fixed.